# Android Studio SDK Manager not opening error but env variable is setup

Tags: android, android-studio

I've installed android Studio and followed the steps provided here in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJ_2_AQboc0)

Studio opens, but the SDK Manager does not. The following is the error:
[image]

I don't understand any of the errors, I'm already using an administrator account on my Computer. I've already installed java on my PC (and even restarted it.) and I've created a path in my JAVA_HOME

I've updated the Android Studio to it's latest version as of today, April 20, 2015

I have Java JRE7 and JDK1.8.0_45 installed in my PC
[image]

I also have setup the environment variable **JAVA_HOME** at my PC
[image]

What else should I do? I can't seem to find similar articles concerning my problem.

Comment: Is your Windows version x64 or x86 ?

Comment: Hi, I'm using a 32 bit windows 7 operating System

Comment: The message says that you are trying to launch 64 bit program in 32 bit operating system. Install 32 bit version of JDK and Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Variable JAVA_HOME, its value to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40

Comment: Please explain further why changing the JAVA_HOME will work for users that run across this.

Comment: well, android doesnt support java 8 yet, so try using latest java 7, and as u said it didnt work, try uninstalling the jdk and the android studio, and download a fresh latest android studio and try again.....if i were you, i would have done that!!